# Vaadin-10/12 Grid Component Renderer Performance issues

Tags: vaadin, vaadin10, vaadin-flow

I am new to vaadin-10/12 versions and previously we used vaadin-7/8 versions, Now we planning to upgrade vaadin-12 version of all our applications. But we facing following problems with vaadin 12 version Grid :

I have created application with using vaadin 12 grid and no.of records i added in the grid 100/1000/10000/100000.

1) Basic grid and lazy loading grid without renderers is working perfectly ( which takes very  less then 1 sec of all cases like 100/1000/10000/100000 ) , But i have problem with componentrenederer with 100/1000/10000/100000  records:

Three TextBox  columns and it takes around    1 second .

Three CheckBox  columns and it takes around   1 second.

Three ComoboBox columns and it takes around   2 second.

columns :
Three TextBox + Three CheckBox + Three ComoboBox = it takes around 3 second.

**Actual my requirement is i want to show more then 10000 records with using componentrenederer with in second.**

**It is any possibility to show 10000 records with in second?**

2) Basic grid (without renderers) problem with selectAll feature:

I added 1000 records and apply selectall it takes 9 secs.

**Any problems with same above features ?**

**Note : Same functionality tested lazy grid and it takes same time and we checked dom elements only visible elements rendered on the browser.**

Thanks,

Amar Bogari